# unable to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, upgrade, 16.10, secure-boot

I was upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 as my wifi driver was not supported by kernel 4.4 used in 16.04. However, I got stuck here during the upgrade process:

[image: upgrading window]

I wasn't able to interact with the terminal to disable secure boot.
I tried to do it on another terminal using `sudo mokutil --enable-validation` command, but I was unable to get `qttranslations5-l10n (amd64)` get installed for completion of the upgrade.

I am working on a Hp pavilion 15au114tx machine dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It is far easier, faster, and more reliable to do a fresh install on 16.10 then to try to fix a failed upgrade. Your files in $HOME should be preserved but I trust you made a backup prior to the upgrade ?

Comment: yeh I do realize it now! is there a way to interact with "distribution upgrade" terminal ?

Comment: Secure boot is usually enabled / disabled in the bios. Hard to know if you can do anything with a failed upgrade. `crtl-alt-F2` bring you to a command prompt ? boot to recovery mode ?